# NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key missing (though present)

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

While working on an iOS app written in Swift, I am having trouble with the Info.plist. Here is the issue:

The unique Info.plist file contained in the project has an `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription` key.

For reference, here is the relevant part of Info.plist:

```
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>The app uses bluetooth to transfer data to a neighbouring device.</string>
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>The app may frequently use bluetooth to transfer data to peers.</string>
```

But when I run the app on my iPhone, I see this error in the Xcode debugging console:

```
  2021-06-06 11:20:21.235717+0900 TheApp[5010:1066154] [access] This app has crashed because
  it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.
  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key
  with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
```

There is already a contradiction at this point that I do not explain.

For some further investigation, I do as follows:

```
  Product
    -> Archive
      -> Distribute App
        -> Development: Distribute to members fo your team.
          -> Export
```

There I change the name TheApp.ipa to TheApp.zip and uncompress it.
Then inside the Payload folder, on TheApp.app I do:

```
  Show Package Contents
```

There I see an Info.plist item which I click to take a look at.

And for some unknown reason the `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription` key is indeed missing.

This last point may explain the error message I was getting earlier, but I still don't know why the key has disappeared.

Anyone who can shed light on this issue will be very welcome.

Comment: This repeats your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67831248/nsbluetoothalwaysusagedescription-present-but-seemingly-invisible-to-the-app. I see how this happened but you might want to delete the earlier question.

Comment: My guess is that the presence of the NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription causes the NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription to be removed. Could you test that hypothesis?

Comment: Yes you are somewhat right, so I removed the previous question. You know the system doesn't like it though, when we remove questions with some answers or comments attached.

Comment: Well, I will try, but I think there are cases (depending on the version of iOS) where you need both keys.

Comment: That's why you're supposed to _edit_ your original question rather than repeating it separately in another form.

Comment: I did the test by removing the NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key, but it did not solve anything. The problem is still there. And what is even weirder is that the NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription is still in the Package contents.

Comment: OK. I see the point.

Comment: Well, so much for that theory. Thanks for trying it!

Comment: The trouble is that I'm not able to reproduce the issue. Do this, please. Look in your Info.plist displayed in English. You should see both Privacy - Bluetooth Always... and Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral usage description entries. If you don't, you've entered one of the names incorrectly. Now build. Now open the Products group of the project navigation and do Show In Finder on the app. Open the app with Show Package Contents. Look in the Info.plist. Are both keys present?

Comment: Yes I see both in the Info.plist. Then doing Show Package Contents (after following your indications) only one key (Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description) is left. The other one (Bluetooth Always Usage Description) has disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

While looking and trying out various things I discovered a duplicate of Info.plist.

```
MyApp copy-Info.plist
```

This ghost Info.plist contained wrong contents and looking at it, that explained all the weird observations I was making.

For some reason the building process was using the ghost file instead of using mine. And the actual Info.plist was ignored.